# PHP htmlspecialchars and character sets issue

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I've got a page that loads content from a database. I have the page set to use utf-8 as such

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I've set the collation on the db to utf8_unicode_ci, and I access the field from mysql using this:

```
$desc = htmlspecialchars($row['description'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

I've done this to fix smart quotes and em-dashes. However, any field that contains those characters is being returned blank now. If I take away the 'UTF-8' parameter in my htmlspecialchars call I get the full text just with questionmark-in-a-diamond characters where the quotes should be. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an empty string back, it probably means there's an invalid UTF-8 character in the content from the database.  You could also set the ENT_IGNORE flag, but I'd recommend doing a binary search with the offending string to try to figure out exactly what the offending character is.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.  See the section under return value.